# how to check the json response array contains the substring

Tags: rest-assured

how to assert the json response array contains a  substring in a string value.

I have tried this but assertion is failed   response.then().body("response.content.Date", Matchers.everyItem(contains("2019-03")  ));

my response body is

```
{
  "response": {
    "totalSize": 2,
    "content": [
      {
        "requestId": " 931-f8222e",
        "name": "gowtham",
        "date": "2019-03-06",
        "issue": "i have a cause"
      },
      {
        "requestId": " 931-f8222e",
        "name": "tharun",
        "date": "2019-03-09",
        "issue": "has a issue in billing"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i want to get all the records in the month(value) and assert the response showing data for given month

Comment: Do you really have a space in `Date` and `Name` elements? Shouldn't it be "Date" instead of " Date"?

Comment: no spaces ,i have corrected it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You were very close. Instead of using `contains` which matches full string, you can use `containsString` to match a substring.

Code:

```
response.then().body("response.content.date", Every.everyItem(Matchers.containsString("2019-03")));
```

Comment: response.then().body("response.content.date", Every.everyItem(Matchers.containsString("2019-03")));       response.then().body("response.content.date", Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.containsString("2019-03") ));        both solved my issue  but what is the difference between  using Every.every and Matchers.every

Comment: @testmail `Every` is a type of `Matcher` while `Matchers` is a class containing static matchers. It's like accessing an `Every` matcher from all of the matchers available, instead of calling it directly. The output will be the same.